# Why does std::stoul convert negative numbers?

Tags: c++, c++11

As shown in http://ideone.com/RdINqa, `std::stoul` does not throw a `std::out_of_range` for negative numbers, but wraps them around. Why is this? Seems like -4 is out of the range of the type `unsigned long` so it should throw.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> **21.5** Numeric conversions
>
> `unsigned long stoul(const string& str, size_t *idx = 0, int base =
>   10);`
>
> *Effects:* ...call[s] `strtoul(str.c_str(), ptr, base)` ... returns the converted result, if any.
>
> *Throws:* ...`out_of_range` if the converted value is outside the range of representable values for the return type.

"Converted value" here is the value returned by `strtoul`. Which, of course, is of type `unsigned long` and so can't be outside of the range of representable values for the return type of `stoul`, which is also `unsigned long`.

As far as I can tell, only `stoi` can throw `out_of_range`, because it returns `int` but uses `strtol` which returns `long`.

Further, the way C standard specifies `strtoul`, it is required to accept the string `"-4"` and return a value equal to `-(unsigned long)4`. Why it's specified this way, I don't know.

Comment: @Aconcagua `strtoul` will consume all digits; it won't stop after say 10th digit (or however many fit into `long long`) as you appear to expect. [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/z98nWovKx)

Comment: Oh, good to know... Just discovered anyway: `errno` gets set to `ERANGE` as well, so *that* is the appropriate check ;)

Comment: @Aconcagua Upon closer inspection, the spec has in fact changed between C++11 and C++14 (my answer was written before C++14). From C++14 onward, it says "Throws `out_of_range` if `strtol`, `strtoul`, `strtoll` or `strtoull` sets `errno` to `ERANGE`, or if the converted value is outside the range of representable values for the return type." C++11 didn't have the `errno` part.