# Parse string to unsigned int with error handling if string represents negative number

Tags: c++, string, type-conversion

Unfortunately parsing the string representation of a negative number to an unsigned int with proper error handling seems way more complicated than one would expect. Neither [std::stoul](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19327845/why-does-stdstoul-convert-negative-numbers), nor strtoul, nor [boost::lexical_cast](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/5494) nor the stringstream approach detect the "error" and happily parse the string "-1" by performing a wrap around.

Is there any other way of converting a string to unsigned int with proper error handling? The way proposed as comment to the [boost bug report](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/5494) seems a bit...strange.

Comment: Why would that fail? Unsigned integer arithmetic is defined as arithmetic mod `2^NumBit`, this cannot overflow nor underflow, letting this fail would not make sense. Yielding the `2^NumBit - 1` is the only meaningful result; if for you cases, `-1 ≠ 2^NumBit - 1`, you should most likely be using signed integers.

Comment: In my case I need to parse user input. Performing a wrap around does not make sense and a negative value is not allowed. I also think your argument is a bit weak since assigning -1 to an unsigned int does not compile instead of silently performing a wrap around. ;)

Comment: *"does not compile"* [News to me.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5ab85f42a156ec4b) :) But seriously, even many members of the standards committee dislike unsigned integers and admit using them all over the standard library was a mistake. ([Source](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/Interactive-Panel-Ask-Us-Anything) 9:50, 42:40, 1:02:50) They just do more harm than good unless you *actually* want mod 2^NumBit arithmetic or are doing bit magic.

Comment: I...uhm...don't know what to say...embarrassing ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no such function/operator in the standard library. You could:

- Check for `-` character in the string beforehand, as already suggested, which, while strange, will work AFAICT

  ```
  int mystrtoul(char const *s, unsigned &y)
  {
      if (strchr(s, '-') == NULL) {
          y = strtoul(s, NULL, 0);
          return 0;
      }
      return -1;
  }
  ```
- Use `strtod()` first. It will detect negative numbers and you can then call `strtoul()` if the number is not negative, like:

  ```
  int yastrtoul(char const *s, unsigned &y)
  {
      if (strtod(s, NULL) >= 0) {
          y = strtoul(s, NULL, 0);
          return 0;
      }
      return -1;
  }
  ```
- Do the whole thing yourself, but be careful as detecting overflow is tricky, because of undefined behavior.

Comment: `strtol(s, NULL, 10) >= 0` should also work: the `strtol` function preserves the sign when bounding the out-of-range values (`LONG_MIN` or `LONG_MAX`)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what is meant by error handling. If you are truly trying to parse out an unsigned int, anytime there is a `-` in the 0th index of your string, you should flag the error, otherwise, parse as normal.

Comment: I want to detect if the input was a positive number and can be assigned to an unsigned int. Checking the first character for being '-' was the proposed solution at the boost bug report, which I find a bit strange

Comment: while it is strange, it's probably going to be the easiest solution. checking one character (especially one in a string) is going to be constant time, so it's not going to hurt performance. worst thing is that it might make your code a little bit uglier.

Comment: `strtoul` etc. allow leading whitespace which is discarded, so just checking the first character is generally insufficient